# Movie from the 80’s or 90’s where it is illegal to smoke cigarettes

Tags: story-identification, movie, dystopia

I have very limited memory of this movie I’m trying to remember but the scene I recall is a man in an alley smoking a cigarette and there are helicopters and police searching for him and he’s running for his life.

I’ve googled for years to no avail. I am pretty sure I saw it (possibly on HBO or Cinemax) when I was a kid in the 80’s or 90’s.

Comment: Sounds like something out of *Demolition Man*.

Comment: Are they chasing him *because* he's a smoker?

Comment: While researching my answer to a different question, I found a (purported) early draft of the *Knight Rider 2010* script in which it was illegal to smoke cigarettes - maybe you read https://web.archive.org/web/20020307184542fw_/http://www.fortunecity.com/tatooine/phlebas/339/id62.htm and misremembered the images in your head as an actual film?

Comment: I think the movie Cats Eye had a segment about a man hiring a company to help him stop smoking and they go to extreme measures.

Comment: @ArlettaS The segment was called "Quitters, Inc", by Stephen king.

Comment: @DavidW I agree it sounds like *Demolition Man*, but it’s not. Unless there’s some directors cut that I haven’t seen.

Comment: The Knight Rider script is an interesting lead! I rewatched Demoltion Man today because ChatGPT lead me there and I didn’t see the scene so I’m back to the beginning when it comes to that one. I am beginning to think I am misremembering or linking the wrong movie or possibly tv show. I can remember the one scene like a vivid memory but everything else is a blur. I will definitely check out Cats Eye because a couple of scenes in that one are burned into my memory. Thank you all for your help so far!

Comment: When I originally posted I was certain I saw it somewhere between 1986-1988 but ChatGPT made me confident it was Demolition Man. I really don’t feel I’d forget such a pivotal scene in a memorable movie when I was around 13. Most movies, tv shows and music are burned into my memory from that time period forward. This is such a tough one for me.

Comment: How prescient. I went from a time when smoking next to a non-smoker at work was allowed to smoking rooms at work to where smoking in the condo one owned had become illegal -- not quite helicopters but I assume one could have been fined or even arrested.

Comment: @Valorum I’m not certain but I know it’s because it is a crime and he is smoking

Comment: I remember in the Judge Dredd comics smoking tobacco was very illegal. Could it be the Sylvester Stallone movie Dredd?

Comment: @JudithJones I’ll check it out! Thank you.